# c# feed a method with x and y values from a chart (polynomial calculation)

Tags: c#, charts, polynomial-math

I have got this method to get a polynomial with my desired degree:

```
public static double[] Polyfit(double[] x, double[] y, int degree)
{
    // Vandermonde matrix
    var v = new DenseMatrix(x.Length, degree + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < v.RowCount; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <= degree; j++) v[i, j] = Math.Pow(x[i], j);
    var yv = new DenseVector(y).ToColumnMatrix();
    QR qr = v.QR();
    // Math.Net doesn't have an "economy" QR, so:
    // cut R short to square upper triangle, then recompute Q
    var r = qr.R.SubMatrix(0, degree + 1, 0, degree + 1);
    var q = v.Multiply(r.Inverse());
    var p = r.Inverse().Multiply(q.TransposeThisAndMultiply(yv));
    Console.WriteLine(p.Column(0).ToString());
    return p.Column(0).ToArray();

}
```

How can I feed the method above with values from my chart (x and y)?

```
chart.Series[0].Points.... ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution is:

```
    ////generate polynomial of degree 4 fiting to the points
    double[] arrayX = new double[chart.Series[0].Points.Count()];
    double[] arrayY = new double[chart.Series[0].Points.Count()];
    double[] arrayResult = { };

    for (int i = 0; i < chart.Series[0].Points.Count(); i++)
    {
        arrayX[i] = chart.Series[0].Points[i].XValue; 
        arrayY[i] = chart.Series[0].Points[i].YValues[0];
    }

    arrayResult = Polyfit(arrayX, arrayY, 4);

    foreach (double element in arrayResult)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(element.ToString());
    }

    double functionVarE = arrayResult[0];
    double functionVarD = arrayResult[1];
    double functionVarC = arrayResult[2];
    double functionVarB = arrayResult[3];
    double functionVarA = arrayResult[4];
    double equationVar = 0;

    //prepare the function series in the graph
    if (chart.Series.IndexOf("function") < 0)
        chart.Series.Add("function");
    chart.Series[2].Points.Clear();
    chart.Series[2].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

    for (int x = -500; x < 1000; x++)  //hardcoding
    {
        equationVar = functionVarA * (Math.Pow(x, 4)) + functionVarB * (Math.Pow(x, 3)) + functionVarC * (Math.Pow(x, 2)) + functionVarD * x + functionVarE;
        chart.Series[2].Points.AddXY(Convert.ToDouble(x), equationVar);
    }
```

This is a working solution I coded. If you see any improvement feel free to tell me!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers
chart1.Series[0].XValueMember
```

Comment: That cant work the method needs double[] and not strings

Comment: @kiliv I am sorry, I copy pasted from one of my applications and forgot to remove that, check it now. Actually This is chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers a get : set property and I was setting it before..

Comment: this are still strings and not double arrays

Comment: Just loop trough the string array and parse it to a double array.

Answer (score 0):

The `Points` property is a getter, so you cannot set a new instance of `DataPointCollection` to it. You should however be able to access methods on the current `DataPointCollection`.

You could try something along the lines of:

```
chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(double, double)
```

You would then iterate the array(s) and set the points manually.

[MSDN DataPointCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.